# VBA: Using Array Index in Location for Right Side of Range.Formula

Tags: vba, excel

Everyone knows at this point you can do something like the following to apply a formula to a range and the cell references on the right side will update dynamically:

```
Range("A1:A10").Formula = "=J2+M2"
```

That is not what I am asking. I am trying to pass an array index into the right side of a `Range.Formula` and I am not getting the results I desire. For starters, here is my code and left side works just fine (mind you the `xl.` is due to this being initiated from MS Access):

```
' Get the new amount of columns since new ones have been added
lastColumn = xl.Cells(1, xl.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

' Create and array of the header names to quickly locate column number
cols = xl.Range(xl.Cells(1, 1), xl.Cells(1, lastColumn)).Value

' Apply the formulas
xl.Range(xl.Cells(2, xl.Match("FCode", cols, 0)), xl.Cells(lastRow, xl.Match("FCode", cols, 0))).Formula =
```

This much applies to the correct range. If I put `"ASD"`, `"=J2+M2"` on the right side, it updates the correct range. The problem comes when I need use `xl.Match(...)` on the right side as part of the formula.

For example:

```
"=ISBLANK(" & xl.Range(xl.Cells(2, xl.Match("NCode", cols, 0)), xl.Cells(2, xl.Match("NCode", cols, 0))) & ")"
```

Returns a `1004: Application-defined or object-defined error`. This should return `=ISBLANK(K2)`, `=ISBLANK(K3)`, `etc.` in the applied range.

Just a simple references that should equal `=K2`, `=K3`, `etc` ends up equaling the value that is in the cell `K2`. For example, `=14` and it applies that to the whole range. It won't even return the values in `K3`, `K4`, `etc`. This is the formula being used for that:

```
"=" & xl.Range(xl.Cells(2, xl.Match("PCode", cols, 0)), xl.Cells(2, xl.Match("PCode", cols, 0)))
```

What am I doing wrong? The reason for doing this is because the column I need to refer to changes between reports, but the header name stays the same. It could be column M in one report, but column Z in another. Up until now I have been using `For Loops`, but they are slow and want to avoid them.

Comment: `Debug.Print` your ISBLANK() formula and I think you'll see it's not what you expect.

Comment: Why don't you use variables and populate them with the different Match results? Then you only need to plug in the variables into the formula and the code will be much easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"=ISBLANK(" & xl.Range(xl.Cells(2, xl.Match("NCode", cols, 0)), _
                       xl.Cells(2, xl.Match("NCode", cols, 0))) & ")"
```

should probably be

```
"=ISBLANK(" & xl.Cells(2, xl.Match("NCode", cols, 0)).Address(false, false) & ")"
```

Comment: Tim just got more progress towards the "Magnificent Man" badge!